# Windows Phone 8.1 ManipulationDelta Event

Tags: c#, windows, animation, windows-phone-8.1, user-input

I'm really confused about this Topic. None of the tutorials I found to e.g. move objects around when there's touch input works. For example they all do something like this:

```
Control.AddHandler(UIElement.ManipulationStartedEvent, new EventHandler
    <ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(Control_ManipulationStarted), true);
```

But there's no ManipulationStartedEventArgs, VS2013 can't find it and there's no way to add a using directive. Are those tutorials old and did MS change the way the ManipulationDelta works?

Adding it with the EventHandler section of the Properties section again doesn't work, no Event is fired no matter what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For manipulation to work the UI Element must have [ManipulationMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode) property set to *something other* than `None` or `System` to be a manipulation event source; i.e Set `ManipulationMode` to `TranslateX` if you want an event to fire on a horizontal pointer movement.

For UI manipulation in Windows Universal you have 3 events:

- [ManipulationStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationstarted)
- ManipulationDelta
- ManipulationCompleted

Each with their own EventArgs under `System.Windows.Input` namespace

- [ManipulationStartedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationstartedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
- ManipulationDeltaEventArgs
- ManipulationCompletedEventArgs

The problem may however be the type of UI Element that you are using, not all accept/generate manipulation events.

Examples of UI Elements that don't:

- `WebView`
- *(I expect `Canvas` but not sure, haven't tested)*

Examples of UI Elements that do:

- `Textblock`
- `ListView`

Comment: The ManipulationMode property was missing. Seems like I completely forgot about that, but I can't remember that it was set in the tutorials. Anyway, now everything is working as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could be of help, also some UIElements do have their `ManipulationMode` set by default to something that can generate Manipulation events.